# admin site attribute error

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I went through the django online tutorial, and i am basically trying to replicate it the tutorial with some modifications of my own. When I create my own models called Request and Response and i go to the admin site to look at these models, it will not let me look at Response, i get an error:

```
    Exception Type: AttributeError
    Exception Value:    
    'Response' object has no attribute 'response'
I am doing the same exact thing they did in the tutorial, and i even put the tutorial code in below my code and the tutorial code works fine, i am not sure what is going on:
```

models.py:

```
 class Request(models.Model):
        vive_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        # pub_date = models.DateField('date published', default=datetime.date.today)
        # location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Not Location Specific")

        def __str__(self):
            return self.vive_title


    class Response(models.Model):
        request = models.ForeignKey(Request)
        response_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        # pub_date = models.DateTimeField("time of response")
        votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.response


    class Question(models.Model):
        question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

        def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
            return self.question_text


    class Choice(models.Model):
        question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
        choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

        def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
            return self.choice_text
```

admin.py

```
from .models import Response, Request, Question, Choice

admin.site.register(Request)
admin.site.register(Response)
admin.site.register(Choice)
admin.site.register(Question)
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Response(models.Model):
        request = models.ForeignKey(Request)
        response_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        # pub_date = models.DateTimeField("time of response")
        votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.response
```

This class hasn't *self.response*. Only request, response_text and votes. You need return other value.

Comment: thank you so much, i don't know how i did not catch this before, that fixed my problem